# difficulty with rust binary tree implementation

Tags: rust, binary-search-tree, rust-obsolete

I am trying to implement a simple binary search tree in Rust but I am having difficulty pinning down an issue with inserting nodes. I am using the following data structures and functions.

```
enum BinaryTree<T> {
    Leaf(T),
    Branch(T, Box<BinaryTree<T>>, Box<BinaryTree<T>>),
    Null,
}

fn createBinarySearchTree(vector: Vec<int>) -> BinaryTree<int> {        
    fn insertNode(val: int, btree: &BinaryTree<int>) -> BinaryTree<int> {
        match btree {
            &Leaf(tval) if val > tval => Branch(tval, box Null, box Leaf(val)),     
            &Leaf(tval) if val < tval => Branch(tval, box Leaf(val), box Null),
            &Branch(tval, box ref left, box ref right) if val > tval => insertNode(val,right),
            &Branch(tval, box ref left, box ref right) if val < tval => insertNode(val,left),
            &Null => Leaf(val),
            &Leaf(lval) if val == lval => Leaf(val),
            &Branch(lval, box ref left, box ref right) if val == lval => fail!("already has a node with {}", lval),
            _ => Null,
        }
    }

    let mut tree = Null;
    for v in vector.iter() {
        tree = insertNode(*v, &tree);
    }

    let immuTree = tree;
    immuTree
}

fn printTree(tree: &BinaryTree<int>) {
    fn innerPrint(prefix: &str, tree: &BinaryTree<int>, level: int) {
        let lvDesc = format!("lv {}", level);
        match tree {
            &Leaf(val) => println!("{}-{} leaf: {}", lvDesc, prefix, val),
            &Branch(val, box ref left, box ref right) => {
                println!("{}-{} node: {}", lvDesc, prefix, val);
                innerPrint("left branch <-", left, level + 1);
                innerPrint("right branch ->", right, level + 1);
            },
            &Null => println!("end"),
        }
    }
    innerPrint("root", tree, 0);
}
```

Upon calling `printTree(&createBinarySearchTree(vec![43,2,45,7,72,28,34,33]))` the tree only prints out `33,34` and unfortunately I cannot debug as compiling with debug info causes a compiler error. Also I have tried to return a branch when I match on branch on inserting but this requires me to clone the leaf/give ownership in ways that I just can't wrap my head around yet. So any help would be much appreciated

Cheers

Comment: "compiling with debug info causes a compiler error" ooooh, sounds like a bug, what's the output?

Comment: I already reported the bug via gitHub. closed it as it was  a dupe see https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/15003

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe these branches to be at fault:

```
&Branch(tval, box ref left, box ref right) if val > tval => insertNode(val, right),
&Branch(tval, box ref left, box ref right) if val < tval => insertNode(val, left),
```

Since you are mutating the original tree, each of those branches looses the original tree root. Supposed fix (untested):

```
&Branch(tval, box ref left, box ref right) if val > tval => Branch(tval, left, insertNode(val, right)),
&Branch(tval, box ref left, box ref right) if val < tval => Branch(tval, insertNode(val, left), right),
```

**EDIT**

Well the idea was right, but you are correct that Rust complains about moving out of the & pointer behind a pattern guard, so I had to do another match inside (which turns out for the better). I also couldn't ignore the naming so I cleaned it up in accordance with Rust coding style:

```
use std::fmt::Show;

enum BinaryTree<T> {
    Leaf(T),
    Branch(T, Box<BinaryTree<T>>, Box<BinaryTree<T>>),
    Null,
}

fn create_binary_search_tree(vector: Vec<int>) -> BinaryTree<int> {
    fn insert_node<T: Copy + Ord + Show>(val: T, btree: BinaryTree<T>) -> BinaryTree<T> {
        match btree {
            Leaf(tval) if val > tval => Branch(tval, box Null, box Leaf(val)),   
            Leaf(tval) if val < tval => Branch(tval, box Leaf(val), box Null),
            Branch(tval, left, right) => match val.cmp(&tval) {
                Greater => Branch(tval, left, box insert_node(val, *right)),
                Less    => Branch(tval, box insert_node(val, *left), right),
                Equal   => fail!("already has a node with {}", tval),
            },
            Null => Leaf(val),
            Leaf(lval) if val == lval => Leaf(val),
            _ => Null,
        }
    }

    let mut tree = Null;
    for v in vector.iter() {
        tree = insert_node(*v, tree);
    }

    let immuTree = tree;
    immuTree
}


fn print_tree(tree: &BinaryTree<int>) {
    fn inner_print(prefix: &str, tree: &BinaryTree<int>, level: int) {
        let lvDesc = format!("lv {}", level);
        match tree {
            &Leaf(val) => println!("{}-{} leaf: {}", lvDesc, prefix, val),
            &Branch(val, box ref left, box ref right) => {
                println!("{}-{} node: {}", lvDesc, prefix, val);
                inner_print("left branch <-", left, level + 1);
                inner_print("right branch ->", right, level + 1);
            },
            &Null => println!("end"),
        }
    }
    inner_print("root", tree, 0);
}

fn main() {
    print_tree(&create_binary_search_tree(vec![43, 2, 45, 7, 72, 28, 34, 33]));
}
```

I verified this code to work in "http://play.rust-lang.org/"